# How to decompose a matrix over a ring $F[X_1,\ldots,X_k]$ as a product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, polynomials, factorization

Let $F$ be a field. Assume any reasonable conditions if needed, such as $F=\mathbb R$, $F=\mathbb C$, $F$ is a finite field, or $F$ has a specific characteristic, etc. Let $C$ be an $n\times1$ matrix over a ring $F[X_1,\ldots,X_k]$. (As a side note, in my situation, $k<n$ and for each entry $c$ of $C$ and for each variable $X_i$, the degree of $X_i$ in $c$ is less than $n$.) I want to factorize $C$ as $AB$, in a way that the following conditions are met as much as possible:

1. The degrees of the polynomials contained in $A$ are small;
2. The number of columns in $A$ (= the number of rows in $B$) is small.

Is there a way to do this? It would be the best if the total degree of each polynomial in $A$ is at most $1$, and the number of rows in $B$ is at most $k$. But these can be relaxed.

What I have thought: Let $\mathfrak c$ be the ideal generated by the polynomials in $C$ and let $\mathfrak b$ be the ideal generated by the polynomials in $B$. Then $\mathfrak c\subseteq\mathfrak b$ should hold. So my question might amount to finding an ideal $\mathfrak b$ containing $\mathfrak c$ such that

- $\mathfrak b$ is not too large (so that the degree of the polynomials in $B$ will be large and the polynomials in $A$ will be small);
- $\mathfrak b$ is generated by small number of elements (so that the number of rows in $B$ will be small).

Comment: If you take $C$ to be the matrix with entries monomials of degree $n-1$ in two variables and if you want $A$ to have linear entries, then I suspect $B$ must have $n-1$ rows ( for example, monomials of degree $n-2$).